# can see someone is doing or can see someone doing? Are both the same?

Tags: usage, sentence-structure

is it the same to put "I can see he is jumping on his bed" and "I can see him jumping on his bed"? I need to use the first one in a picture description. Can I use it? Would that not sound strange to an native speaker?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It can *potentially* mean the same.  Though "I can see him jumping on his bed" can also be interpreted as "I imagine him jumping on his bed."  Admittedly, this is a strange interpretation of the sentence and probably not true, but you should be aware of this second meaning.

Used in another context:

> "I can see him laying on the beach with shades on."

In this interpretation, the speaker doesn't *literally* mean the person is within sight on the beach.  It means it *imagines* him laying on the beach with shades on.